Move all files with .sql extension in postgres image
I have below type of folder structure
project-folder/
├── Dockerfolder/
│   └── Dockerfile
└── pg/
    ├── folder1/
    │   ├── 01-create-db.sql
    │   ├── 02-create-tables.sql
    │   └── 03-seed-data.sql
    └── folder2/
        ├── 01-create-db.sql
        ├── 02-create-tables.sql
        └── 03-seed-data.sql

I want to build a docker image based on postgres:latest base image where when the container is started I want to run all the .sql files on the server created
if I put the .sql file in same directory (Dockerfolder) as Dockerfile then I am able to copy them in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory using COPY pg /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ line but I want to have the files only .sql inside the docker-entrypoint-initidb.d when I have the above folder structure
I have tried to push the entier structure (with folder and files) inside docker-entrypoint-initidb.d but then it do not run those .sql file when i create a container out of it. this makes me believe that docker-entrypoint-initidb.d need .sql file in its root.
I have tried the below 2 version of docker file
V1
FROM postgres:latest as builder

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgresuser \
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    POSTGRES_HOST=postgreshost 
    

# Copy all the init.sql files from the subdirectories to the Docker container
COPY pg /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
# RUN docker-entrypoint.sh postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data

V2
# Use the official PostgreSQL image as the base image
FROM postgres:latest

# Create the directory in the image
# RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# Copy .sql files from the host to the image
COPY ../pg /pg

# Move all .sql files from init-scripts to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN find /pg -name "*.sql" -exec cp {} /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ \;

Can you help me how can i do that? In short I want to roam around all the directory, subdirectory, sibling directories and find all .sql file and copy those files only in docker-entrypoint-initidb.d

P.S. if you have time do you have any other brand new approach that
you can suggest to achieve the result. Essentially I want to have a
container which is when spinned will be ready with my databases, my
tables inside those and my master data inside those tables.(not all
tables have master data)


Does your application have some sort of database-migration framework?  In the setup you show, if you add another table, you'll have to delete and recreate the database to add the new table.  A migration system would avoid the specific problem you're running into here, it would make it possible to change the database schema later, and it would work in non-Docker setups too.

I am working on a brand new project for my client, a next release would be far away, but you are making sense. there is no migration that I am having here. In a way I am saying the day I will release I will have all the tables and schemas, but yes I have one DB which is third party DB, who sends new data every 6 month and will have to 'fill' that new data in DB. any other approach that you suggest? @DavidMaze

You say you want to run your scripts every time the container starts. But scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are not run every time the container starts. They run when the database is initialized. Hence the 'initdb' in the directory name. If a database exists when the container starts, no scripts are run.

I am okay if it runs only first time, I am going to create volume to store data so I can restore the data. @HansKilian
